# Can't close Kivy app or avoid fullscreen

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I am new to Kivy and trying to find my way around. Whenever I create and run an app, it displays as a full-screen that I am unable to close without disconnecting the power (which I know is not ideal, but that's exactly why I am desperate to fix it!).

Shortcuts that are suggested to work (Esc, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Alt+break) don't. I have attempted changing the config settings at the beginning of the script as follows:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 0)
Config.write()
```

I've also tried variations on the theme - 0 as a string, 1 as both an integer and string (and trying to provide a width and height for the window) but with no perceivable change. Even if this did work, it would not be the ideal fix given that I would probably want to be able to run things full-screen in the end!

Given that each time I've tried changing something I've had to restart the pi by disconnecting the power, playing around has been quite time-consuming! 
Does anybody have any suggestions about how I should proceed?

I'm currently using:
Raspberry Pi 2 Model B connected to normal TV (many people having problems have been using a touchscreen, but that is not true for me)
Raspbian Jessie, Linux 8
Python 2.7
I'm afraid I don't know how to check details about the Kivy module I have downloaded.

I'm very new to this, so apologies if I don't manage to provide all of the relevant information.

Full code I am trying to run (excluding the above config changes):

```
import kivy  
kivy.require('1.9.2') #may be part of the problem - not 100% sure this is correct 

from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.label import Label  


class MyApp(App):  

    def build(self):  
        return Label(text='Hello world')  


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Are you using the special rpi graphics backend? This draws directly to the fbo, so there's no alternative to having the app be fullscreen, though the inability to exit it would be a bug.

Comment: I don't know - how would I find out?

Comment: Check the log output

Comment: I can't check the log output because the app is running full screen in the way!

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround you could just do :

```
def build(self):
    button = Button(text = 'Exit', size_hint = (.1, .05),
                    pos_hint = {'x':0, 'y':0})
    button.bind(on_press = self.on_quit)
    self.layout = FloatLayout()
    self.layout.add_widget(button)

    return self.layout

def on_quit(self):
    exit()
```

Which would provide you with an exit button. For your fullscreen problem it's weird, can you provide some more code ?

EDIT:

Can you try this ? :

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', 0)
Config.write()
```

Comment: I've updated the original question with the code. Thanks for your help - I'll certainly try the work-around for now!

Answer (score 0):

To work around this issue, you can change the full screen to fake so kivy can exit on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'fake')
Config.write()
```

Also, try to run the code in command line prompt. Avoid raspberry pi's desktop environment while running kivy apps. This will free up pi's memory for running kivy.